# Creating Spark dataframe from numpy matrix

Tags: numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

it is my first time with PySpark, (Spark 2), and I'm trying to create a toy dataframe for a Logit model. I ran successfully the [tutorial](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-classification-regression.html) and would like to pass my own data into it.

I've tried this:

```python
%pyspark
import numpy as np
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint

df = np.concatenate([np.random.randint(0,2, size=(1000)), np.random.randn(1000), 3*np.random.randn(1000)+2, 6*np.random.randn(1000)-2]).reshape(1000,-1)
df = map(lambda x: LabeledPoint(x[0], Vectors.dense(x[1:])), df)

mydf = spark.createDataFrame(df,["label", "features"])
```

but I cannot get rid of :

```python
TypeError: Cannot convert type <class 'pyspark.ml.linalg.DenseVector'> into Vector
```

I'm using the ML library for vector and the input is a double array, so what's the catch, please? It should be fine according to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/linalg/Vectors.html).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mixing functionality from ML and MLlib, which are not necessarily compatible. You don't need a `LabeledPoint` when using `spark-ml`:

```python
sc.version
# u'2.1.1'

import numpy as np
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors

df = np.concatenate([np.random.randint(0,2, size=(1000)), np.random.randn(1000), 3*np.random.randn(1000)+2, 6*np.random.randn(1000)-2]).reshape(1000,-1)
dff = map(lambda x: (int(x[0]), Vectors.dense(x[1:])), df)

mydf = spark.createDataFrame(dff,schema=["label", "features"])

mydf.show(5)
# +-----+-------------+ 
# |label|     features| 
# +-----+-------------+ 
# |    1|[0.0,0.0,0.0]| 
# |    0|[0.0,1.0,1.0]| 
# |    0|[0.0,1.0,0.0]| 
# |    1|[0.0,0.0,1.0]| 
# |    0|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
# +-----+-------------+
```

**PS:** As of Spark 2.0, the RDD-based APIs in the spark.mllib package have entered maintenance mode. The primary Machine Learning API for Spark is now the DataFrame-based API in the spark.ml package. [[ref.]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html#announcement-dataframe-based-api-is-primary-api)

Comment: I think it's very important to clear these things up because this is where the mess begins. It's not the first time OPs mix up between them and at a certain point they ask themselves what should they use.

Comment: yh when you see it first time its gets a bit confusing :) https://www.nodalpoint.com/spark-classification/

Comment: I think you want to use `column_stack` instead of `concatenate`

Answer (score 12):

From Numpy to Pandas to Spark:

```
data = np.random.rand(4,4)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=list('abcd'))
spark.createDataFrame(df).show()
```

**Output**:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+
|                  a|                  b|                 c|                  d|
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+
| 0.8026427193838694|0.16867056812634307|0.2284873209015007|0.17141853164400833|
| 0.2559088794287595| 0.3896957084615589|0.3806810025185623| 0.9362280141470332|
|0.41313827425060257| 0.8087580640179158|0.5547653674054028| 0.5386190454838264|
| 0.2948395900484454| 0.4085807623354264|0.6814694724946697|0.32031773805256325|
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: The thing is, if you are to continue processing this data with Spark ML, you are going to need something like [`VectorAssembler`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler) further downstream, in order to convert the 4 columns into a single one, like `features` in my answer, as Spark ML needs the features in this form...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is easy to solve. You're using the `ml` and the `mllib` API at the same time. Stick to one. Otherwise you get this error.

This is the solution for the `mllib`API:

```python
import numpy as np
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint

df = np.concatenate([np.random.randint(0,2, size=(1000)), np.random.randn(1000), 3*np.random.randn(1000)+2, 6*np.random.randn(1000)-2]).reshape(1000,-1)
df = map(lambda x: LabeledPoint(x[0], Vectors.dense(x[1:])), df)

mydf = spark.createDataFrame(df,["label", "features"])
```

For the `ml` API, you don't really need `LabeledPoint` anymore. Here is an [example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.regression.LinearRegression). I would suggest to use the `ml` API since the `mllib` API is going to deprecated soon.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer as well. I awarded desertnaut's and upvoted yours. Thanks a lot!

Comment: upvoted too, since it is complementary to mine (`mllib`). It is not visible now, but both our answers came with just 2 minutes difference - cool... :)